# How can I provide a mini version of a very large application to my users

Tags: performance, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, database-replication

My users are really frustrated over the bad performance of a large Lotus Notes application we have (not web).  it is currently 10Gb and have approx 500.000 documents and it contains readers fields.

What I would like to do is create a mini version of the application application as most users are only interested in the last years documents.

The big application can't be archived or moved at this time so I'm thinking about providing a new mini replica and do a selective replication to only include this years documents.

The problem I have is that the full version of the application need to be on all servers which means that I will get both the full version and mini version on the same server with the same replica id which seem a bit scary.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can't have two databases with the same replica ID on a server. If you do, you are going to have a bad time.

Comment: Simon is right.  Don't do it!

Comment: I know, that's why I ask the question

Comment: What about moving the heavy / dead stuff off to another NSF/s and have them connect to it via links in the documents. It should dramatically lower the footprint of the main database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen lots of different approaches to this problem, from simple to way over-engineered.  Sadly, I think I've been the designer of a couple of the way over-engineered approaches.  Fortunately, I've learned some lessons.  Here's what I think is the lowest-tech approach:

What you want to do first is to make a design-only copy of the database.  I'll call it productiondocs.ntf.  I'll refer to the original as alldocs.nsf.

Add two agents to productiondocs.ntf, and make sure that they are protected against design refresh/replace.  Call the first agent "synch", and set it to run on new or modified documents, and write code in to simply copy the new/modified docs into alldocs.nsf.  Make sure to check isValid to protect against processing deleted documents in this agent's main loop.   Call the second agent "purge". Write code to check the date (created, mod, or a data field in the document, depending on the rule you want to enforce) and delete docs that are more than one year old.

Now, you can use selective replication -- but just once.  Make a selective replica of alldocs.nsf, containing only one year's worth of docs, and call it yeardocs.nsf.  Then make a non-replica copy of yeardocs.nsf and call it production.nsf.  Finally, replace the design of production.nsf using production.ntf.  Double-check that the agents are there and that they are protected against design refresh/replace operations.  (Some versions of designer screwed this up!)  Schedule synch to run as often as you need, and schedule purge to run daily or weekly.  Replicate production.nsf to all servers, and move your users over to production.nsf.

(Note: you could do it in reverse, keeping your users in the existing database after purging it; but honestly I think you'll get an extra performance boost by starting with a clean new NSF so that's why I wrote it up the way I did.)

Comment: I gave you a vote for that answer, impressive. not sure that is the solution I am after though, need something simpler. Currently thinking about if I am allowed to remove one replica from one of the servers and create a selective formula replica instead. this way I can direct the users to one server for the mini version and another server for the full version.

Comment: You can do that, but I have to say that the above is the simplest safe solution that I can recommend.  IMHO selective replication is truly evil.  I know it's a supported feature that's been around forever, but I do not trust it.  I've seen things go wrong way too many times. For example, an administrator initiates replication from his client instead of issuing a server 'rep' or 'pull' command, and selective replication is bypassed. Worse, for no apparent reason replication times go way up in some replication cycles while seeming to be normal in others.

Comment: Regarding that last comment, I actually have a suspcicion as to what causes the long replication times. I've never been able to prove it definitively, but I did once collect a lot of evidence that implicated duplicate replication formulas in the NSF, and which suggested strongly that a bug in the selective replication management UI was responsible for creating duplicates any time someone went in just to LOOK at the formula.  If they press OK instead of Cancel from that dialog, without making changes, a duplicate was sometimes created.

Comment: @ThomasAdrian I think following Richard's advice is far simpler than replication formulas.

Answer (score 0):

I really like Richard's solution, but I recently implemented a derivation of that which I like so far. Basically, put any meta-data from each document into a separate database that is your "index" and when they open the index document, it opens the document in alldocs.nsf (and closes the index document).

To do this, write an agent in alldocs.nsf that creates the index document whenever a document is modified or saved. It should only copy the fields you want to use for indexing (the meta-data). Sample code to do this (without the subroutines or functions it calls) from my **Copy Incident to Main** agent:

```
Sub Initialize
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim maindb As NotesDatabase ' Main SIR
Dim mainincidents As NotesView ' view in Main SIR
Dim maindoc As NotesDocument ' document in Main SIR
Dim projectdoc, nextprojectdoc As NotesDocument ' document in this database
Dim ndc As NotesDocumentCollection ' unprocessed documents in this database
Dim fieldItem As NotesItem
Dim reportnumber, value, formtype As Variant
Dim fieldsToCopy (10) As String 
Dim reason As String

On Error GoTo errorhandler 

Call StartAgentLogging ( session )

Set thisdb = session.Currentdatabase

' find all unstamped documents
Set ndc = thisdb.Unprocesseddocuments

If ndc.Count = 0 Then
    Call agentLog.LogAction ( "No incidents to process" )
    Exit Sub
End If

maindbfilepath = DetermineKeyword("MAINSIR")
Set maindb = session.Getdatabase("","")
Call maindb.Open("", maindbfilepath)

If Not maindb.Isopen Then
    reason = "Main Security database could not be found at " & maindbfilepath
    Call agentLog.LogAction ( reason )
    MessageBox reason, 16, "Error"
    Exit Sub
End If

Set mainincidents = maindb.Getview("(Incidents for Upload)")
Set projectdoc = ndc.Getfirstdocument()
fieldsToCopy (0) = "ReportType"
fieldsToCopy (1) = "ReportNumber"
fieldsToCopy (2) = "ReportDate"
fieldsToCopy (3) = "IncidentDate"
fieldsToCopy (4) = "ProjectName"
fieldsToCopy (5) = "ProjectCountry"
fieldsToCopy (6) = "ProjectLocation"
fieldsToCopy (7) = "ReporterName"
fieldsToCopy (8) = "ReporterPhone"
fieldsToCopy (9) = "ReporterEmail"
fieldsToCopy (10) = "Appointment"

While Not projectdoc Is Nothing
    formtype = projectdoc.GetItemValue ("Form")
    If formtype(0) = "Incident" Then
        ' check to see if that exists in the main SIR
        reportnumber = projectdoc.GetItemValue("ReportNumber")
        Call agentLog.LogAction ( "Checking " & reportnumber(0) )
        Set maindoc = mainincidents.GetDocumentByKey(reportnumber(0), True)
        Call agentLog.LogAction ( "Accessing " & reportnumber(0) )

        If maindoc Is Nothing Then
            Call agentLog.LogAction ( "Main does not contain " & reportnumber(0) & " creating new document." )
            ' if not, create new document
            Set maindoc = maindb.Createdocument()
            maindoc.Form = "Incident"

            ForAll fieldname In fieldsToCopy
                Call agentLog.LogAction ( "Field name: " & fieldname ) 
                Set fieldItem = projectdoc.Getfirstitem(fieldname)
                Call maindoc.Copyitem(fieldItem, fieldname)
            End ForAll

            Call maindoc.Save(True, False)
            Call CreateNotice ( maindoc )
        Else
            Call agentLog.LogAction ( "Main contains " & reportnumber(0) & " updating document." )
            ' if it does, update data
            ForAll fieldname In fieldsToCopy
                Call agentLog.LogAction ( "Field name: " & fieldname ) 
                value = projectdoc.GetItemValue(fieldname)
                Call maindoc.ReplaceItemValue(fieldname, value(0))
            End ForAll
        End If

        'Path and filename
        Call maindoc.Replaceitemvalue("Path", thisdb.Filepath)
        Call maindoc.Save(True, False)
        Call agentLog.LogAction ( "Saved " & reportnumber(0) )
    Else
        Call agentLog.LogAction ( "Project form is " & projectdoc.Form(0) )
    End If

    ' stamp document as processed
    Set nextprojectdoc = ndc.GetNextDocument(projectdoc)
    Call session.Updateprocesseddoc(projectdoc)
    Set projectdoc = nextprojectdoc
Wend 

exiting:
    Exit Sub
errorhandler:' report all errors in a messagebox
    reason = "Error #" & CStr (Err) & " (" & Error & ") when creating incident in Main database, on line " & CStr (Erl)
    Call agentLog.LogAction ( reason )
    MessageBox reason, 16, "Error" 
    Resume exiting
End Sub
```

Then, you need to add code into the onLoad event of the index form in the index database. I put mine in an agent called by a ToolsRunMacro, but you could put it in directly. This is my **Open Project Copy** agent.

```
Sub Initialize
' this button opens the incident report in the project database
Dim ws As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim reportdb As NotesDatabase
Dim view As NotesView
Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
Dim thisdoc, reportdoc As NotesDocument
Dim filepath, reportnumber As Variant
Dim baseurl, opener, unid As String

Call StartAgentLogging ( session )
Set thisdb = session.Currentdatabase

Set uidoc = ws.CurrentDocument
Set thisdoc = uidoc.Document
filepath = thisdoc.GetItemValue ( "Path" )
reportnumber = thisdoc.GetItemValue ( "ReportNumber" )

Set reportdb = session.GetDatabase (thisdb.Server, filepath (0), False )
If reportdb Is Nothing Then
    MessageBox ( "Could not find Project Security Incident Report database" & Chr$(10) & thisdb.Server & "\" & filepath(0) )
    Call agentLog.LogAction ( "Could not find Project Security Incident Report database" & Chr$(10) & thisdb.Server & "\" & filepath(0) )
    Exit Sub
End If
If Not reportdb.Isopen Then
    Call reportdb.Open(thisdb.Server, filepath (0)) 
End If
Set view = reportdb.GetView ( "Incidents" )
Set reportdoc = view.GetDocumentByKey ( reportnumber(0) )
If reportdoc Is Nothing Then
    MessageBox ( "Could not find Report #" & reportnumber(0) )
    Call agentLog.LogAction ( "Could not find Report #" & reportnumber(0) )
    Exit Sub
End If

Call uidoc.Close
unid = reportdoc.UniversalID
baseurl = reportdb.NotesURL
opener = Left$ ( baseurl, InStr ( baseurl, "?" ) -1 ) & "/Incidents/" & unid & "?OpenDocument"
Call ws.URLOpen ( opener )
Call agentLog.LogAction ( "Opened Report #" & reportnumber(0) )
End Sub
```

Now, you could limit the index database to only documents for the most recent year or see how it works when all documents are in it. A lot really depends on how much data you need to have available in views.

In my situation, the index database contains index documents for documents from many databases and serves as a central access point for the "full data" databases. It's still in testing, so I'm not sure how well it will work for me, but I thought I'd offer it as a possibility for you.